# (Tapestry v5.3.5) Contributing a non-caching SymbolSource

Tags: tapestry, symbols

I need my application to read it's configuration from a database source but I have to apply my own caching mechanism to satisfy flexibility with updating my configuration and performance (Not hitting the database whenever a value is needed)

The service performing the caching mechanism is `SymbolSourceImpl`. Since I need tapestry to cache the cachable values such as JVM options. I need to contribute **another** symbol source. But `SymbolObjectProvider` (Contributed to `MasterObjectProvider`) holds only one instance of `SymbolSource` and I cannot override `SymbolSource` default binding so I thought about contributing a whole another symbol object provider to the `MasterObjectProvider` just as tapestry did with the default `SymbolObjectProvider`.

But here comes an issue when I tried to contribute my own symbol object provider:

```
@Contribute(MasterObjectProvider.class)
public static void setupDBSYmbolObjectProviders(OrderedConfiguration<ObjectProvider> configuration) {
    configuration.addInstance("DBSymbol", **DBSymbolObjectProvider**.class, OrderConstraintBuilder.before("Symbol").build());
}
```

My **DBSymbolObjectProvider** constructor looks like this:

```
public DBSymbolObjectProvider(IDBSymbolSource symbolSource, @Builtin TypeCoercer typeCoercer) {
    this.symbolSource = symbolSource;
    this.typeCoercer = typeCoercer;
}
```

Tapestry resolved `TypeCoercer` but it couldn't resolved `IDBSymbolSource` and threw the following exception which is logical because the `MasterObjectProvider` isn't yet constructed to resolve `IDBSymbolSource`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'RegistryStartup': Unable to instantiate class com.skycomm.IpKaizenTAModule as a module: Exception constructing service 'MasterObjectProvider': Error invoking service contribution method com.skycomm.ipkaizen.services.CoreModule.setupDBSYmbolObjectProviders(OrderedConfiguration): Exception constructing service 'MasterObjectProvider': Construction of service 'MasterObjectProvider' has failed due to recursion: the service depends on itself in some way. Please check org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.MasterObjectProviderImpl(List, OperationTracker) (at MasterObjectProviderImpl.java:33) via org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at TapestryIOCModule.java:49) for references to another service that is itself dependent on service 'MasterObjectProvider'.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:75)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
    at $Runnable_440ab1f4dbb6.delegate(Unknown Source)
    at $Runnable_440ab1f4dbb6.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.performRegistryStartup(RegistryImpl.java:325)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryWrapper.performRegistryStartup(RegistryWrapper.java:80)
    at com.skycomm.IpKaizenTA.main(IpKaizenTA.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate class com.skycomm.IpKaizenTAModule as a module: Exception constructing service 'MasterObjectProvider': Error invoking service contribution method com.skycomm.ipkaizen.services.CoreModule.setupDBSYmbolObjectProviders(OrderedConfiguration): Exception constructing service 'MasterObjectProvider': Construction of service 'MasterObjectProvider' has failed due to recursion: the service depends on itself in some way. Please check org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.MasterObjectProviderImpl(List, OperationTracker) (at MasterObjectProviderImpl.java:33) via org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at TapestryIOCModule.java:49) for references to another service that is itself dependent on service 'MasterObjectProvider'.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ModuleImpl.instantiateModuleInstance(ModuleImpl.java:447)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ModuleImpl.access$1200(ModuleImpl.java:39)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ModuleImpl$6$1.invoke(ModuleImpl.java:355)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ModuleImpl$6.run(ModuleImpl.java:350)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier$2.invoke(ConcurrentBarrier.java:200)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier$2.invoke(ConcurrentBarrier.java:197)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withWrite(ConcurrentBarrier.java:140)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withWrite(ConcurrentBarrier.java:206)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ModuleImpl$7.invoke(ModuleImpl.java:366)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:85)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ModuleImpl.getModuleBuilder(ModuleImpl.java:374)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ContributionDefImpl.invokeMethod(ContributionDefImpl.java:113)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ContributionDefImpl.contribute(ContributionDefImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl$9.run(RegistryImpl.java:633)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl$1.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:51)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl$1.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:48)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.run(OperationTrackerImpl.java:47)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.run(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:76)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.addToOrderedConfiguration(RegistryImpl.java:629)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.getOrderedConfiguration(RegistryImpl.java:483)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl$2.invoke(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl$2.invoke(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:107)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl.getOrderedConfiguration(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AbstractServiceCreator.getOrderedConfiguration(AbstractServiceCreator.java:123)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AbstractServiceCreator.access$200(AbstractServiceCreator.java:35)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AbstractServiceCreator$1.findResource(AbstractServiceCreator.java:103)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.DelegatingInjectionResources.findResource(DelegatingInjectionResources.java:38)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.calculateInjection(InternalUtils.java:231)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.access$000(InternalUtils.java:50)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$4.invoke(InternalUtils.java:289)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$4.invoke(InternalUtils.java:286)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.calculateParameters(InternalUtils.java:293)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$23.invoke(InternalUtils.java:1488)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$23.invoke(InternalUtils.java:1483)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.createConstructorConstructionPlan(InternalUtils.java:1480)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.getPlan(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:52)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.createObject(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:46)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AdvisorStackBuilder.createObject(AdvisorStackBuilder.java:63)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:54)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'MasterObjectProvider': Error invoking service contribution method com.skycomm.ipkaizen.services.CoreModule.setupDBSYmbolObjectProviders(OrderedConfiguration): Exception constructing service 'MasterObjectProvider': Construction of service 'MasterObjectProvider' has failed due to recursion: the service depends on itself in some way. Please check org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.MasterObjectProviderImpl(List, OperationTracker) (at MasterObjectProviderImpl.java:33) via org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at TapestryIOCModule.java:49) for references to another service that is itself dependent on service 'MasterObjectProvider'.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:75)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
    at $MasterObjectProvider_440ab1f4dbb7.delegate(Unknown Source)
    at $MasterObjectProvider_440ab1f4dbb7.provide(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.getObject(RegistryImpl.java:871)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ObjectLocatorImpl.getObject(ObjectLocatorImpl.java:57)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$6.run(InternalUtils.java:371)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl$1.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:51)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl$1.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:48)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.run(OperationTrackerImpl.java:47)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.run(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:76)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.run(RegistryImpl.java:1119)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.injectIntoFields(InternalUtils.java:338)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ModuleImpl.instantiateModuleInstance(ModuleImpl.java:433)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking service contribution method com.skycomm.ipkaizen.services.CoreModule.setupDBSYmbolObjectProviders(OrderedConfiguration): Exception constructing service 'MasterObjectProvider': Construction of service 'MasterObjectProvider' has failed due to recursion: the service depends on itself in some way. Please check org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.MasterObjectProviderImpl(List, OperationTracker) (at MasterObjectProviderImpl.java:33) via org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at TapestryIOCModule.java:49) for references to another service that is itself dependent on service 'MasterObjectProvider'.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ContributionDefImpl.invokeMethod(ContributionDefImpl.java:130)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ContributionDefImpl.contribute(ContributionDefImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl$9.run(RegistryImpl.java:633)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl$1.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:51)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl$1.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:48)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.run(OperationTrackerImpl.java:47)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.run(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:76)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.addToOrderedConfiguration(RegistryImpl.java:629)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.getOrderedConfiguration(RegistryImpl.java:483)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl$2.invoke(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl$2.invoke(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:107)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl.getOrderedConfiguration(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AbstractServiceCreator.getOrderedConfiguration(AbstractServiceCreator.java:123)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AbstractServiceCreator.access$200(AbstractServiceCreator.java:35)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AbstractServiceCreator$1.findResource(AbstractServiceCreator.java:103)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.DelegatingInjectionResources.findResource(DelegatingInjectionResources.java:38)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.calculateInjection(InternalUtils.java:231)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.access$000(InternalUtils.java:50)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$4.invoke(InternalUtils.java:289)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$4.invoke(InternalUtils.java:286)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.calculateParameters(InternalUtils.java:293)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$23.invoke(InternalUtils.java:1488)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$23.invoke(InternalUtils.java:1483)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.createConstructorConstructionPlan(InternalUtils.java:1480)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.getPlan(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:52)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.createObject(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:46)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'MasterObjectProvider': Construction of service 'MasterObjectProvider' has failed due to recursion: the service depends on itself in some way. Please check org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.MasterObjectProviderImpl(List, OperationTracker) (at MasterObjectProviderImpl.java:33) via org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at TapestryIOCModule.java:49) for references to another service that is itself dependent on service 'MasterObjectProvider'.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:75)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
    at $MasterObjectProvider_440ab1f4dbb7.delegate(Unknown Source)
    at $MasterObjectProvider_440ab1f4dbb7.provide(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.getObject(RegistryImpl.java:871)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ObjectLocatorImpl.getObject(ObjectLocatorImpl.java:57)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.calculateInjection(InternalUtils.java:257)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.access$000(InternalUtils.java:50)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$4.invoke(InternalUtils.java:289)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$4.invoke(InternalUtils.java:286)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.calculateParameters(InternalUtils.java:293)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$23.invoke(InternalUtils.java:1488)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$23.invoke(InternalUtils.java:1483)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.createConstructorConstructionPlan(InternalUtils.java:1480)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.getPlan(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:52)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.createObject(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl$4.invoke(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl.autobuild(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl.autobuild(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:170)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AbstractConfigurationImpl.instantiate(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ValidatingOrderedConfigurationWrapper.addInstance(ValidatingOrderedConfigurationWrapper.java:95)
    at com.skycomm.ipkaizen.services.CoreModule.setupDBSYmbolObjectProviders(CoreModule.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ContributionDefImpl.invokeMethod(ContributionDefImpl.java:120)
    ... 134 more
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: Construction of service 'MasterObjectProvider' has failed due to recursion: the service depends on itself in some way. Please check org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.MasterObjectProviderImpl(List, OperationTracker) (at MasterObjectProviderImpl.java:33) via org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at TapestryIOCModule.java:49) for references to another service that is itself dependent on service 'MasterObjectProvider'.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    ... 169 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Construction of service 'MasterObjectProvider' has failed due to recursion: the service depends on itself in some way. Please check org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.MasterObjectProviderImpl(List, OperationTracker) (at MasterObjectProviderImpl.java:33) via org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at TapestryIOCModule.java:49) for references to another service that is itself dependent on service 'MasterObjectProvider'.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:52)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    ... 173 more
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can have an updatable Symbols even if you get your custom `SymbolSource` to work(I will come back to how you can do that). The reason being how symbols are inserted into the services. They are inserted into the fields and are not transformed into indirect accessor methods. So even if you changed the value, your custom `SymbolSource` will not be called again to fetch that value.

**How to contribute your own `SymbolSource`**
Just decorate the SymbolSource service

```
public class AppModule {

    public SymbolSource decorateSymbolSource(
        final SymbolSource symbolSource) {
        return new MyCustomSymbolSource(symbolSource);
    }

}
```

With `MasterObjectProvider`, it doesn't stay a service, it is called as an object. Still if you want to use `MasterObjectProvider` always use `@Local` for local services that helps resolve services and prevent recursion.